# NSTextView (inside NSScrollView) - how can i know if scrollbar is required?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

After i set a string in the NSTextView object, can i determine if the scroll bar will be shown?

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare the height of the `NSTextView` to the height of the `NSScrollView`.

```
if ([textView frame].size.height > [scrollView frame].size.height) {
    //Scrollbar will be shown.
}
else {
    //Scrollbar will not be shown.
}
```